# What's the maximum number of read replicas you can create with the Cloud SQL service on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I can't find this anywhere in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/) and I don't want to incur costs to figure it out. How many read replica's can you create with the Cloud SQL service on Google Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is effectively no limit to what number of replica's native MySQL can theoretically support. Although the required [`server_id`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id)  might provide a hard upper limit of 4294967295 replica's you'll likely run into other resource limits well before that.

Barring an actual upper limit enforced by the Cloud SQL service specific to the number replica's the 4000 concurrent connections [resource limit/quota](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quotas) is for example already one such limit...